# Why does my CalcOddIntegers method always return zero?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer

This method is supposed to take user input for the length of the array, and then the integers that are part of the array, and return the amount of odd numbers in the array. However, it always returns zero for the count of odd integers and I am unsure as to why. The scanner is declared outside of this method.

```
        
        System.out.print("Enter length of sequence\n");
        int length = console.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[length];
        System.out.print("Enter the sequence: \n");
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = console.nextInt();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < length -1; i++); {
            if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("The count of odd integers in the sequence is %d\n", count);
    }
```

Example of console:

```
2. Calculate the factorial of a given number
3. Calculate the amount of odd integers in a given sequence
4. Display the leftmost digit of a given number
5. Calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers
6. Quit


3
Enter length of sequence
4
Enter the sequence: 
1
2
3
4
The count of odd integers in the sequence is 0
```

I have tried experimenting with the `for` statements with different variables to see if something was conflicting but nothing has worked.

Comment: do you see anything wrong with `for (i = 0; i < length -1; i++);` ?

Comment: Put some extra `System.out.println` statements in your code and see why your array values are all zero.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Wombat Other threads I saw used just ```length``` however I get an index out of bounds error otherwise. Is this another problem?

Comment: The semi-colon !

Comment: Oh my god. I have been backstabbed, betrayed, and quite possibly bamboozled. I think I am going to take a break for the night. thank you so much.

Comment: sleep tight, don't let the code bugs bite

Comment: Yea ... you can't code when you are [muddle-headed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muddle-Headed_Wombat) :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon (;) in the line

> for (i = 0; i < length -1; i++);
> the semi-colon terminates the loop hence an assumption that your line does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

After the second `for` there is a semicolon that shouldn't be there. The syntax is technically correct however, there is nothing to execute so the block that checks for odd numbers is going to be executed only once. I suggest using a debugger that will help you troubleshoot issues easier.